# Math.js is slow to multiply 2 big matrices

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, math, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to speed-up matrices multiplications in pure javascript. Multiplications appear to be very slow above a few hundreds of lines, over the minute on a thousand of lines: you'll see the execution time bellow.

How would you solve this? We are working on a split + parallelization solution in Node.js so I'm looking for the best options to optimize it in pure javascript. My solution has to adapt the parallelized flows itself to the number of CPU threads available (that is unknown at design time).

Some data :

```
const math = require("mathjs");

// a1 is a 1000x1000 float matrix
// b1 is a 1000x400
math.multiply(a1, b1)
// runs in 19.6 seconds on a CPU 4.2Ghz

// a2 is 1600x1200
// b2 is 1200x800
math.multiply(a2, b2)
// runs in 78 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

**Array lookup optimization**

Arrays are associative lookup tables in JavaScipt - they are inefficient by nature. An optimization of this kind of array access

```
var array = some_2D_Array;
var nRows = array.length;
var nCols = array[0].length;

for( var r = 0; r < nRows; ++r) {
    for( var c = 0; c < nCols; ++c) {
        // do something with array[r][c];
    }
}
```

is to replace it with

```
var array = some_2D_Array;
var nRows = array.length;
var nCols = array[0].length;

for( var r = 0; r < nRows; ++r) {
    var aRow = array[r];  // lookup the row once
    for( var c = 0; c < nCols; ++c) {
        // do something with aRow[c];
    }
}
```

which avoids searching the `array` object for the row array within each iteration of the inner loop. Performance gain will depend on the JS engine and the number of inner iterations.

**Typed Array Usage**

Another alternative could be to use a one dimensional typed array to avoid associative array index lookup instead of computing it. Here's some test code I ran in Node so see what difference it might make:

```js
function Mat (rows, cols) {
    var length = rows*cols,
        buffer = new Float64Array( length)
    ;
    function getRow( r) {
        var start = r*cols,
            inc = 1;
        return { length: cols, start, inc, buffer};
    }
    function getCol( c) {
        var start = c,
            inc = cols;
        return { length: rows, start, inc, buffer};
    }
    function setRC(r,c, to) {
        buffer[ r*cols + c] = to;
    }
    this.rows = rows;
    this.cols = cols;
    this.buffer = buffer;
    this.getRow = getRow;
    this.getCol = getCol;
    this.setRC = setRC;

}
Mat.dotProduct = function( vecA, vecB) {
    var acc=0,
        length = vecA.length,
        a = vecA.start, aInc = vecA.inc, aBuf = vecA.buffer,
        b = vecB.start, bInc = vecB.inc, bBuf = vecB.buffer
    ;
    if( length != vecB.length) {
        throw "dot product vectors of different length";
    }
    while( length--) {
        acc += aBuf[ a] * bBuf[ b];
        a += aInc;
        b += bInc;
    }
    return acc;
}
Mat.mul = function( A, B, C) {
    if( A.cols != B.rows) {
        throw "A cols != B.rows";
    }
    if( !C) {
        C = new Mat( A.rows, B.cols);
    }
    for( var r = 0; r < C.rows; ++r) {
        var Arow = A.getRow(r);
        for (var c = 0; c < C.cols; ++c) {
            C.setRC( r, c, this.dotProduct( Arow, B.getCol(c)));
        }
    }
    return C;
}

function test() {
    // A.cols == B.rows
    let side = 128;
    let A = new Mat( side, side)
    let B= new Mat( side, side);
    A.buffer.fill(1)
    B.buffer.fill(1)
 console.log( "starting test");
    let t0 = Date.now();
    Mat.mul( A,B);
    let t1 = Date.now();

    console.log( "time: " + ((t1-t0)/1000).toFixed(2) +" seconds");
}
test()
```

Results for multiplying two square matrices (1.1Ghz Celeron):

> ```
> // 128 x 128 = 0.05 seconds
> // 256 x 256 = 0.14 seconds  
> // 512 x 512 = 7 seconds
> // 768 x 768 = 25 seconds
> // 1024 x 1024 = 58 seconds
> ```

The differences in CPU speed *suggest* this approach could be significantly faster **but** ... the code is experimental, the system had no other load and timings were for array multiplication alone - they exclude time taken to decode and populate the array with data. Any serious gain would need to be proven in practice.

I eventually decided that when multiplying two square matrices together, doubling the side dimension used should make the operation take 8 times as long: four times as many result elements to calculate and twice as many elements in vectors used to calculate dot products. The comparative times for 512 x 512 and 1024 x 1024 multiplications fit in line with this expectation.

Comment: yes, I do this variable set prior the second loop. But would you totally redo the algorithm or would you still use the math.js lib? We have a beginning of a solution by splitting the matrix band-wise or tile-wise of various sizes depending on the number of CPUs and A matrix size, B matrix size... Then we still use Math.js to compute the sub matrix. It's very experimental...

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed answer! I'll test this in details.
In order to reduce the execution time, I'm currently exploring possibilities to parallelize the code execution with child process or worker threads. The last options sounds more accurate and up-to-date.

I'll post my code as soon as I can make this work properly. It seems there is serious communication cost with the other threads before computing anything.

Somebody ever tried such fine grain parallelization with worker threads?

Comment: FYI, Just found a shared memory package but never used it myself: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mmap-object

Comment: Oh thanks! I was benchmarking different solutions for passing large data sets from the main thread to the workers and, indeed, so far files are the best option. Thank you for this lib. I'll post my tests results as soon as I'm done